# Why are changes to coffeescript files not being compiled when my Rails 3.2.0 app is in development mode?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, coffeescript, asset-pipeline

Normally, any changes I make to `.js.coffee` files in my Rails 3.2.0 app in development mode take effect when I refresh the page. All of a sudden, this is not happening. If I do `rake assets:precompile`, then the changes are shown, but then if I do `rake assets:clean` they go back to not being shown. What is causing this?

Edit: Restarting the server makes the changes show. Why isn't this happening automatically as before?

Edit: Here is my development.rb

```
Myapp::Application.configure do
  # Settings specified here will take precedence over those in config/application.rb

  # In the development environment your application's code is reloaded on
  # every request. This slows down response time but is perfect for development
  # since you don't have to restart the web server when you make code changes.
  config.cache_classes = false

  # Log error messages when you accidentally call methods on nil.
  config.whiny_nils = true

  # Show full error reports and disable caching
  config.consider_all_requests_local       = true
  config.action_controller.perform_caching = false

  # Don't care if the mailer can't send
  config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = false

  # Print deprecation notices to the Rails logger
  config.active_support.deprecation = :log

  # Only use best-standards-support built into browsers
  config.action_dispatch.best_standards_support = :builtin

  # Raise exception on mass assignment protection for Active Record models
  config.active_record.mass_assignment_sanitizer = :strict

  # Log the query plan for queries taking more than this (works
  # with SQLite, MySQL, and PostgreSQL)
  config.active_record.auto_explain_threshold_in_seconds = 0.5

  # Do not compress assets
  config.assets.compress = false

  # Expands the lines which load the assets
  config.assets.debug = true
  config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { :host => 'localhost:3000' }

  config.log_level = :warn


end
```

Comment: What do you config your development.rb

Comment: Something else must have changed. What does your application.rb file look like? Any new plugin/code since it stopped working?

Answer (score 1):

I'm quite new in Rails (well... I only learn programming for <3 months

I would guess:

You or some installation change your config in config/application.rb

Can you check in the file:

Is `config.assets.initialize_on_precompile` being `false`?

Change to `true` and try again.

Also check `config.assets.compile`. Is it `true`?

You might change the default value in Rails 3.2. So, I suggest you to think why the change(s) happens.

Comment: This answer is still good for Rails 5! `config.assets.compile` needed to be changed from `false` to `true`. It was in `production.rb`